# Do not see login window in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: login-screen

Yesterday I did a correct end of my computer session.
When I started this morning, I saw the red startup screen, but I did not see my name and the login window.
I tried to press Enter and then entered my password.
After that I was connected and could work as before.

Please now my question:
What can I do in order to receive my name and the login window again?

Many thanks in advance for each answer.
Kind regards,
Gaston Verhulst

Comment: Is a second display connected? Ubuntu cannot always tell whether a display is on or off and may have sent the login widget to the wrong screen.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you are right, yesterday, for an application, I had connected our smart TV to my computer with a HDMI-cable.
And after that I did not remove the cable.
I was thinking, I let that cable connected.
I have to thank you very much for your answer with the helping question.
Kind regards,
Gaston Verhulst.